# load balancing node.js with pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, load-balancing, pm2

I'm trying to make the cluster same instance of my node.js application using pm2 and the example:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {  
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world");
}).listen(8080);
```

and start by:

```
pm2 start app.js -i 4
```

pm2 lists only one instance, which of course runs in cluster mode, but there only one process.

Has anyone tried to use pm2 and faced the same? I'm using windows.

ThankS!

Comment: How much CPUs do you have on your machine ? A process can only run on a single CPU core at a time. There’s nothing more to gain if your machine only has a single core.

Comment: @PierreMaoui 4 cores, it's not single core machine.

Comment: @PierreMaoui, I started with no daemon enabled and process started, I don't know why, but it works.